# Vagrant provisioning - installing ruby version on rbenv fails

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, rbenv

I'm having problems with installing Ruby version using Rbenv on Ubuntu 14.04 (on Vagrant, Berkshelf, VirtualBox running on Windows 10).

Here is Berksfile:

```
source "https://supermarket.chef.io"

cookbook 'apt'
cookbook 'build-essential'
cookbook 'mysql', '5.5.3'
cookbook 'postgresql', '~> 4.0.6'
cookbook 'ruby_build'
#cookbook 'rbenv', git: 'https://github.com/aminin/chef-rbenv.git'
#cookbook 'rbenv', git: 'https://github.com/chef-rbenv/chef_rbenv'
cookbook 'ruby_rbenv', git: 'https://github.com/chef-rbenv/ruby_rbenv' #'~> 1.0.1' 
cookbook 'vim'
cookbook 'nodejs', '~> 2.4.4'
cookbook 'chef-vagrant-frontback', path: 'chef-vagrant-frontback'
```

Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.require_version '>= 1.5'

# Change these two paths to folders 
# FRONTEND  = "../linkip-frontend/"
BACKEND_PATH   = "../linkip-backend/"
BACKEND_NAME   = "linkip-backend"

def require_plugins(plugins = {})
  needs_restart = false
  plugins.each do |plugin, version|
    next if Vagrant.has_plugin?(plugin)
    cmd =
      [
        'vagrant plugin install',
        plugin
      ]
    cmd << "--plugin-version #{version}" if version
    system(cmd.join(' ')) || exit!
    needs_restart = true
  end
  exit system('vagrant', *ARGV) if needs_restart
end

require_plugins \
  'vagrant-bindfs' => '0.4.8', 
  #'vagrant-librarian-chef-nochef' => '0.2.0', 
  'vagrant-berkshelf' => '4.1.0',
  'vagrant-vbguest' => '0.12.0' 

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000 
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 4567, host: 4567

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
  end

  config.vm.synced_folder "#{BACKEND_PATH}", "/project/#{BACKEND_NAME}",
    # Tell Vagrant to use rsync for this shared folder.
    type: "rsync",
    rsync__auto: "true",
    rsync__exclude: ".git/",
    owner: "vagrant",
    group: "vagrant",
    id: "shared-folder-id"

  # config.vm.synced_folder "#{FRONTEND}", "/project/#{FRONTEND}",
  #   # Tell Vagrant to use rsync for this shared folder.
  #   type: "rsync",
  #   rsync__auto: "true",
  #   rsync__exclude: ".git/",
  #   owner: "vagrant",
  #   group: "vagrant",
  #   id: "shared-folder-id"

  config.berkshelf.enabled = true

  # Use Chef Solo to provision our virtual machine
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks", "site-cookbooks"]

    chef.add_recipe "apt"
    chef.add_recipe "nodejs"
    chef.add_recipe "ruby_build"
    chef.add_recipe "ruby_rbenv::user"
    #chef.add_recipe "rbenv::vagrant"
    chef.add_recipe "vim"
    chef.add_recipe "mysql::server"
    chef.add_recipe "mysql::client"
    chef.add_recipe "chef-vagrant-frontback"

    # Install Ruby 2.2.1 and Bundler
    # Set an empty root password for MySQL to make things simple
    chef.json = {
      rbenv: {
        user_installs: [{
          user: 'vagrant',
          rubies: ["2.2.1"],
          global: "2.2.1",
          gems: {
            "2.2.1" => [
              { name: "bundler" }, 
              { name: "rake" }, 
              { name: "rails", 
                version: "4.2.4"
              }
            ]
          }
        }]
      },
      mysql: {
        server_root_password: ''
      }
    }
  end
end
```

And this the part of the log where it starts showing erros:

```
==> default: [2016-07-12T02:53:13+00:00] INFO: Building ruby_rbenv_ruby[2.2.1 (vagrant)] (vagrant), this could take a while...
==> default:
==> default: * ruby_rbenv_script[rbenv install 2.2.1  (vagrant)] action run
==> default:
==> default: * script[rbenv install 2.2.1  (vagrant)] action run
==> default:
==> default:         [execute] Downloading ruby-2.2.1.tar.bz2...
==> default:                   -> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.1.tar.bz2
==> default:                   Installing ruby-2.2.1...
==> default:
==> default:                   BUILD FAILED
==> default:  (Ubuntu 14.04 using ruby-build 20160602)
==> default:
==> default:                   Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196
==> default:
==> default: Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196.log
==> default:
==> default:
==> default: Last 10 log lines:
==> default:                   make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196/ruby-2.2.1/ext/fiddle/libffi-3.2.1'
==> default:                   linking shared-object fiddle.so
==> default:                   /usr/bin/ld: ./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a(raw_api.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
==> default:                   ./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
==> default:                   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
==> default:                   make[2]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-linux/fiddle.so] Error 1
==> default:                   make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196/ruby-2.2.1/ext/fiddle'
==> default:                   make[1]: *** [ext/fiddle/all] Error 2
==> default:                   make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196/ruby-2.2.1'
==> default:                   make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
==> default:
==> default:
==> default:
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default:
==> default:         Error executing action `run` on resource 'script[rbenv install 2.2.1  (vagrant)]'
==> default:         ================================================================================
==> default:
==> default:         Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
==> default:         ------------------------------------
==> default:         Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
==> default:         ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160712-29543-1b85p2w" ----
==> default:         STDOUT:
==> default:         STDERR: Downloading ruby-2.2.1.tar.bz2...
==> default:         -> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.1.tar.bz2
==> default:         Installing ruby-2.2.1...
==> default:
==> default:         BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 14.04 using ruby-build 20160602)
==> default:
==> default:         Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196
==> default:         Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196.log
==> default:
==> default:         Last 10 log lines:
==> default:         make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196/ruby-2.2.1/ext/fiddle/libffi-3.2.1'
==> default:         linking shared-object fiddle.so
==> default:
==> default:
==> default: /usr/bin/ld: ./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a(raw_api.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
==> default:
==> default:         ./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
==> default:         collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
==> default:
==> default: make[2]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-linux/fiddle.so] Error 1
==> default:         make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196/ruby-2.2.1/ext/fiddle'
==> default:         make[1]: *** [ext/fiddle/all] Error 2
==> default:         make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196/ruby-2.2.1'
==> default:         make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
==> default:         ---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160712-29543-1b85p2w" ----
==> default:         Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160712-29543-1b85p2w" returned 1
==> default:
==> default:         Cookbook Trace:
==> default:         ---------------
==> default:         /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/files/lib/chef_compat/monkeypatches/chef/runner.rb:41:in `run_action'
==> default:         /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv/providers/ruby.rb:78:in `perform_install'
==> default:         /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv/providers/ruby.rb:38:in `block in class_from_file'
==> default:         /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/files/lib/chef_compat/monkeypatches/chef/runner.rb:41:in `run_action'
==> default:
==> default:         Resource Declaration:
==> default:         ---------------------
==> default:         # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv/providers/script.rb
==> default:
==> default:          40:   script new_resource.name do
==> default:          41:     interpreter 'bash'
==> default:          42:     code script_code
==> default:          43:     user new_resource.user if new_resource.user
==> default:          44:     creates new_resource.creates if new_resource.creates
==> default:          45:     cwd new_resource.cwd if new_resource.cwd
==> default:          46:     group new_resource.group if new_resource.group
==> default:          47:     returns new_resource.returns if new_resource.returns
==> default:          48:     timeout new_resource.timeout if new_resource.timeout
==> default:          49:     umask new_resource.umask if new_resource.umask
==> default:          50:
==> default:          51:     environment(script_environment)
==> default:          52:   end
==> default:          53: end
==> default:
==> default:
==> default:         Compiled Resource:
==> default:         ------------------
==> default:         # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv/providers/script.rb:40:in `run_script'
==> default:
==> default:         script("rbenv install 2.2.1  (vagrant)") do
==> default:           action [:run]
==> default:           retries 0
==> default:           retry_delay 2
==> default:           default_guard_interpreter :default
==> default:           command "rbenv install 2.2.1  (vagrant)"
==> default:           backup 5
==> default:           environment {"RBENV_ROOT"=>"/home/vagrant/.rbenv", "USER"=>"vagrant", "HOME"=>"/home/vagrant"}
==> default:           returns [0]
==> default:           user "vagrant"
==> default:           code "export RBENV_ROOT=\"/home/vagrant/.rbenv\"\nexport PATH=\"${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:$PATH\"\neval \"$(rbenv init -)\"\nrbenv install 2.2.1 \n"
==> default:           interpreter "bash"
==> default:           declared_type :script
==> default:           cookbook_name "ruby_rbenv"
==> default:         end
==> default:
==> default:         Platform:
==> default:         ---------
==> default:         x86_64-linux
==> default:
==> default:
==> default: [2016-07-12T03:17:44+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
==> default:
==> default:
==> default:
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default:
==> default:       Error executing action `run` on resource 'ruby_rbenv_script[rbenv install 2.2.1  (vagrant)]'
==> default:       ================================================================================
==> default:
==> default:       Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
==> default:       ------------------------------------
==> default:       script[rbenv install 2.2.1  (vagrant)] (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv/providers/script.rb line 40) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
==> default:       ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160712-29543-1b85p2w" ----
==> default:       STDOUT:
==> default:       STDERR: Downloading ruby-2.2.1.tar.bz2...
==> default:       -> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.1.tar.bz2
==> default:       Installing ruby-2.2.1...
==> default:
==> default:       BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 14.04 using ruby-build 20160602)
==> default:
==> default:
==> default: Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196
==> default:       Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196.log
==> default:
==> default:       Last 10 log lines:
==> default:       make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196/ruby-2.2.1/ext/fiddle/libffi-3.2.1'
==> default:       linking shared-object fiddle.so
==> default:       /usr/bin/ld: ./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a(raw_api.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
==> default:       ./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
==> default:       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
==> default:       make[2]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-linux/fiddle.so] Error 1
==> default:       make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196/ruby-2.2.1/ext/fiddle'
==> default:       make[1]: *** [ext/fiddle/all] Error 2
==> default:       make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196/ruby-2.2.1'
==> default:       make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
==> default:       ---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160712-29543-1b85p2w" ----
==> default:       Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160712-29543-1b85p2w" returned 1
==> default:
==> default:       Cookbook Trace:
==> default:       ---------------
==> default:       /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/files/lib/chef_compat/monkeypatches/chef/runner.rb:41:in `run_action'
==> default:       /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv/providers/ruby.rb:78:in `perform_install'
==> default:       /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv/providers/ruby.rb:38:in `block in class_from_file'
==> default:       /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/files/lib/chef_compat/monkeypatches/chef/runner.rb:41:in `run_action'
==> default:
==> default:       Resource Declaration:
==> default:       ---------------------
==> default:       # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv/providers/ruby.rb
==> default:
==> default:        72:     rbenv_script "#{command} #{which_rbenv}" do
==> default:        73:       code command
==> default:        74:       user rbenv_user if rbenv_user
==> default:        75:       root_path rbenv_prefix if rbenv_prefix
==> default:        76:       environment rbenv_env if rbenv_env
==> default:        77:       action :nothing
==> default:        78:     end.run_action(:run)
==> default:        79:
==> default:        80:     Chef::Log.debug("#{new_resource} build time was " \
==> default:        81:       "#{(Time.now - install_start) / 60.0} minutes")
==> default:
==> default:  82:
==> default:
==> default:
==> default:  83:     new_resource.updated_by_last_action(true)
==> default:
==> default:
==> default:  84:   end
==> default:
==> default:        85: end
==> default:
==> default:       Compiled Resource:
==> default:       ------------------
==> default:       # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv/providers/ruby.rb:72:in `perform_install'
==> default:
==> default:       ruby_rbenv_script("rbenv install 2.2.1  (vagrant)") do
==> default:         action [:nothing]
==> default:         retries 0
==> default:         retry_delay 2
==> default:         default_guard_interpreter :default
==> default:         declared_type :rbenv_script
==> default:         cookbook_name "ruby_rbenv"
==> default:         user "vagrant"
==> default:         code "rbenv install 2.2.1 "
==> default:         returns [0]
==> default:       end
==> default:
==> default:       Platform:
==> default:       ---------
==> default:       x86_64-linux
==> default:
==> default:
==> default:
==> default:
==> default:     ================================================================================
==> default:     Error executing action `install` on resource 'ruby_rbenv_ruby[2.2.1 (vagrant)] (vagrant)'
==> default:     ================================================================================
==> default:
==> default:     Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
==> default:     ------------------------------------
==> default:     ruby_rbenv_script[rbenv install 2.2.1  (vagrant)] (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv/providers/ruby.rb line 72) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: script[rbenv install 2.2.1  (vagrant)] (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv/providers/script.rb line 40) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
==> default:     ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160712-29543-1b85p2w" ----
==> default:     STDOUT:
==> default:     STDERR: Downloading ruby-2.2.1.tar.bz2...
==> default:     -> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.1.tar.bz2
==> default:     Installing ruby-2.2.1...
==> default:
==> default:     BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 14.04 using ruby-build 20160602)
==> default:
==> default:     Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196
==> default:     Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196.log
==> default:
==> default:     Last 10 log lines:
==> default:     make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196/ruby-2.2.1/ext/fiddle/libffi-3.2.1'
==> default:     linking shared-object fiddle.so
==> default:
==> default: /usr/bin/ld: ./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a(raw_api.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
==> default:
==> default:
==> default: ./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
==> default:     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
==> default:     make[2]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-linux/fiddle.so] Error 1
==> default:     make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196/ruby-2.2.1/ext/fiddle'
==> default:     make[1]: *** [ext/fiddle/all] Error 2
==> default:     make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196/ruby-2.2.1'
==> default:
==> default: make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
==> default:
==> default:
==> default: ---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160712-29543-1b85p2w" ----
==> default:
==> default:     Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160712-29543-1b85p2w" returned 1
==> default:
==> default:     Cookbook Trace:
==> default:     ---------------
==> default:     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/files/lib/chef_compat/monkeypatches/chef/runner.rb:41:in `run_action'
==> default:     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv/providers/ruby.rb:78:in `perform_install'
==> default:     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv/providers/ruby.rb:38:in `block in class_from_file'
==> default:     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/files/lib/chef_compat/monkeypatches/chef/runner.rb:41:in `run_action'
==> default:
==> default:     Resource Declaration:
==> default:     ---------------------
==> default:     # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv/recipes/user.rb
==> default:
==> default:      47:       rbenv_ruby "#{rubie} (#{rbenv_user['user']})" do
==> default:      48:         definition rubie
==> default:      49:         user rbenv_user['user']
==> default:      50:         root_path rbenv_user['root_path'] if rbenv_user['root_path']
==> default:      51:       end
==> default:      52:     end
==> default:
==> default:
==> default:
==> default:
==> default:
==> default: Compiled Resource:
==> default:
==> default: ------------------
==> default:     # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv/recipes/user.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in from_file'
==> default:
==> default:     ruby_rbenv_ruby("2.2.1 (vagrant)") do
==> default:       action [:install]
==> default:       retries 0
==> default:       retry_delay 2
==> default:       default_guard_interpreter :default
==> default:       declared_type :rbenv_ruby
==> default:       cookbook_name "ruby_rbenv"
==> default:       recipe_name "user"
==> default:       definition "2.2.1"
==> default:       user "vagrant"
==> default:       rbenv_action "install"
==> default:     end
==> default:
==> default:     Platform:
==> default:     ---------
==> default:     x86_64-linux
==> default:
==> default:
==> default: [2016-07-12T03:17:44+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
==> default:
==> default: Running handlers:
==> default: [2016-07-12T03:17:44+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: Running handlers complete
==> default: [2016-07-12T03:17:44+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: Chef Client failed. 3 resources updated in 27 minutes 25 seconds
==> default: [2016-07-12T03:17:44+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2016-07-12T03:17:44+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
==> default: [2016-07-12T03:17:44+00:00] ERROR: ruby_rbenv_ruby[2.2.1 (vagrant)] (vagrant) (ruby_rbenv::user line 47) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: ruby_rbenv_script[rbenv install 2.2.1  (vagrant)] (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv/providers/ruby.rb line 72) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: script[rbenv install 2.2.1  (vagrant)] (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv/providers/script.rb line 40) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
==> default: ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160712-29543-1b85p2w" ----
==> default: STDOUT:
==> default: STDERR: Downloading ruby-2.2.1.tar.bz2...
==> default: -> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.1.tar.bz2
==> default: Installing ruby-2.2.1...
==> default:
==> default: BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 14.04 using ruby-build 20160602)
==> default:
==> default: Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196
==> default: Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196.log
==> default:
==> default: Last 10 log lines:
==> default: make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196/ruby-2.2.1/ext/fiddle/libffi-3.2.1'
==> default: linking shared-object fiddle.so
==> default: /usr/bin/ld: ./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a(raw_api.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
==> default: ./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
==> default: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
==> default: make[2]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-linux/fiddle.so] Error 1
==> default: make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196/ruby-2.2.1/ext/fiddle'
==> default: make[1]: *** [ext/fiddle/all] Error 2
==> default: make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160712025313.30196/ruby-2.2.1'
==> default: make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
==> default: ---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160712-29543-1b85p2w" ----
==> default: Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160712-29543-1b85p2w" returned 1
==> default: [2016-07-12T03:17:44+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

I've tried to do it with different versions of rbenv cookbooks but it seems that the error is the same. Anyone has encountered this error before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so after some digging I found this info on official ruby-build [github page](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#build-failure-of-fiddle-with-ruby-220)

So since I wanted to use provisioning and didn't want users to install anything by them own I added to Berksfile this cookbook:

`cookbook 'libffi-dev', git: 'https://github.com/zchee/libffi-dev-cookbook'`

abd to Vagrantfile this line:

`chef.add_recipe "libffi-dev"`

right after line with apt.

The whole project is [here](https://github.com/OndrejKu/vagrant-frontback) if anyone would like to play with it.